# XSLT 1.0 format String date into other format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

At my `XSLT 1.0` document I have the following element that contains a String representation of date:

```
Product/CreateDate =  2017-06
```

I need to format this String into the following String: `06/2017`

Please show how it can be done with `XSLT 1.0`

**UPDATED**

This is my current XSLT structure:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Product/CreateDate, '-', '/')" />
<xsl:if test="not(Product/CreateDate) or (Product/CreateDate='')">
    &#8212;
</xsl:if>
```

right now it prints: `2017/06`  but I need to print `06/2017` instead

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?  --  P.S. Please provide a [mcve]. As it is, it's hard to tell if your input is `<CreateDate>2017-06</CreateDate>` or `<elem>Product/CreateDate =  2017-06</elem>`. Likewise for the output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have updated my question with current XSLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Product/CreateDate, '-')" />  
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>  
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(Product/CreateDate, '-')" />
```

Or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Product/CreateDate, 6)" />  
<xsl:text>/</xsl:text>  
<xsl:value-of select="substring(Product/CreateDate, 1, 4)" />
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. One more question - is this code safe for NPE in case of null Product/CreateDate ?

Comment: If `CreateDate` is empty or non-existing, the result will be a string consisting of a single slash character. If you want something else, you will need to wrap this in a `xsl:choose` instruction.

Comment: @alexanoid, XPath does not have any concept of "null" (nor does it have any concept of "pointer" or "exception") so the concept of an NPE is completely meaningless in XPath.